# TokenInput Autocomplete in RTL language

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-tokeninput

I'm trying this [TokenInput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) JQuery and it's really cool.
How can turn everything to RTL language?
I mean: the filling of the input field, the suggestions, the "searching..." label..

Maybe this is general question and not TokenInput question...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#my-text-input").tokenInput("http://localhost:18627/Home/SeriesAutoComplete", {
            theme: "facebook",
            searchingText : "searcing"
        });
    });
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like someone may have already implemented this, and shared it on GitHub. Check out these pull requests.

https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput/pull/536/commits

I haven't tested it myself.

Comment: Thanks :) I tried it, didn't work that well I'll keep looking at that direction